# Printf statment is producing output that doesnt include the data i entered through scanner

Tags: java, arrays

Once i have entered my data in an earlier statement into the array i then attempt to fetch this data and print but i get a random output of data, which you can see in the attach image.

my code is below:

```
private void listStudent()
{
    {       
System.out.printf("%s %-7s %14s %10s","ID","First Name","Last Name","Age\n");
for (int i= 0; i<count; ++i)
 {
 System.out.println(arr[i]);   
}
System.out.println();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine();


public class Student {
private String fname;
private final String lname;
double age;
private final String id;
int count;
```

This is my code from the student.java file

```
Student(String id, String fname, String lname, double age, int count) 
{
   this.id = id;
   this.fname = fname;
   this.lname = lname;
   this.age = age;
   this.count = count;
}
```

[This is what the output of the code i get is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GbM0.png)

Comment: Java is very different from Javascript. Please make an attempt to figure out the name of the language you're trying to write code in, and tag your questions appropriately.

Comment: It is unclear what you are question is

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you want to ask is connected to the following output:
Student@55f96302.
It happens because of the line

```
System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

As I understand you are trying to print the Student object information but Java does not work in such way - if you will just print an array item (which is an object), it will print you **Classname@hash**.

In order to print real student data, your Student class should also contain getter for the values. So Student class will look like:

```
public class Student {

    private String id;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private double age;
    private int count;

    Student(String id, String fname, String lname, double age, int count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.age = age;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public double getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then in 'for' loop you need to do the following:

```
for (int i= 0; i<count; ++i)
 {
 System.out.println(arr[i].getId() + arr[i].getFname() + arr[i].getLname());   
}
```

and so on.

Comment: Thank you very much, i see where my error was and that makes so much sense now!!!